# React cleanup function doesn't clean state

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

experts,
please explain me, why in the following code the state of the property won't be cleaned in the useEffect cleanup function?

My component:

```
export default function TestComp() {

  let { id } = useParams();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  console.log('[TestComp] called...');

  const cleanup = () => {
    console.log('[TestComp] old value', value);
    setValue(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[TestComp] id changed: ', id);
    console.log('[TestComp] value in useEffect', value);
    setValue(id);
    return () => {
      cleanup();
    }
  }, [id]);

  return (<React.Fragment>Test id: {id}</React.Fragment>)
}
```

Console output:

```
[TestComp] called... TestComp.js:8
[TestComp] old value satellites:MTP TestComp.js:11
[TestComp] id changed:  satellites:MTP TestComp.js:16
[TestComp] value in useEffect satellites:FPGA TestComp.js:17
[TestComp] called... 2 TestComp.js:8
[TestComp] old value satellites:FPGA TestComp.js:11
[TestComp] id changed:  satellites:FNE TestComp.js:16
[TestComp] value in useEffect satellites:MTP TestComp.js:17
[TestComp] called... TestComp.js:8
```

I expect that, when useEffect will be called for the 2. time, the **value** wull be cleaned up and is *null*, but it still keeps the old value:

```
value in useEffect satellites:MTP TestComp.js:17
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will cleanup your state when your component is unmounted.Basically If you want to implement componentWillUnmount. than you have to return in useEffect.  For more reference see this article : https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/

Comment: Try moving the log to another `useEffect` with `value` as dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return function from useEffect just cleans up the previous effects before applying the next effects. But main problem in your code is

```
    const cleanup = () => {
    console.log('[TestComp] old value', value);
    setValue(null); // This is not prefer way to use setValue here.
}
```

Normally, During cleans up we unsubscribe from external service/subscription but here you are changing the state which make no sense here and immediately getting update by useEffect **setValue** that run and just after **setValue** inside cleanup called which is also reason of calling effect again,

*Check your code after adding setTimeout in your useEffect.*

```
`useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[TestComp] id changed: ', id);
    console.log('[TestComp]:Effect value in useEffect', value);
    setValue(id);
    return () => {
      setTimeout(()=> cleanup(), 5000)
    }
  }, [id]);`
```

Possible Solution -

- In above case you are using **id**, lift up this property to parent component and pass it as property to TestComp component.
- when effect runs whole component get re-render and scope get destroyed but all state maintain inside the closure of **useState** hooks.

[working example for above situation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-cleanup)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add another `useEffect`, because, in the current situation, the `cleanup` function will run only on **unmount** which is pretty useless for the current logic.

```
export default function TestComp() {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  console.log('[TestComp] called...');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[TestComp] id changed: ', id);
    console.log('[TestComp] value in useEffect', value);
    setValue(id);

    /* v Useless cleanup because the component unmounts anyway,
         the `value` state will be cleaned automatically.
    return () => {
      cleanup();
    }
    */
  }, [id]);

  // ^ Firstly, the `value` changed on id change
  // v Secondly, the `value` will be reset on `value` change
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[TestComp] old value', value);
    setValue(null);
  }, [value]);

  return <>Test id: {id}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of the sequence in which things happen.

`useEffect` will 'capture' value as part of a closure when it is called, i.e. when the `TestComp` function is called. When id changes React will schedule a call to the cleanup function and then a call to the effect. However `TestComp` is not called again until after the new effect function has been called.

You can see this in the log as each `old value` from the cleanup function is immediately followed by `id changed` from the effect function.

And because the new effect functions 'captures' value from when `TestComp` was called, it will not see the value set by the cleanup function.

Also note, at least from testing I saw React complain about `value` and `cleanup` not being in the dependencies for `useEffect`.